# ZF2 Form: How to provide field hints

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form-element, hint

I've been learning how to use ZF2 from the book Learn ZF2: Learning by Example by Slavey Karadzhov. In it, he shows how to build forms using annotations. One particularly helpful feature is the "pattern" attribute. If you add a pattern to the form, there's a really cool JavaScript function that checks does client-side validation. If a field's input doesn't match the desired pattern, a groovy little tooltip of sorts pops up pointing out the field(s) that have problems and telling you what needs to be fixed.

I was wondering: is there a similar system in ZF2 so that, when a field is highlighted, a similar tooltip pops up to give hints on what exactly needs to be entered into a field? For example, for a password field it could give the requirements for the password. And if this isn't built in, is there a module out there somewhere that does this? I've done a bunch of Googling on this subject, but I've come up empty so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since zf2 come's with an Twitter Bootstrap implementation you could just use the [Tooltip functionality.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)
I personally do not use anotation's in my forms for various reasons, one being the performance hit you take.

within your `YourForm.php` just set some data attributes and you should be good to go:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name'       => 'submit',
        'type'       => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value'          => 'Save',
            'id'             => 'submitbutton',
            'data-toggle'    => 'tooltip',
            'data-placement' => 'left',
            'title'          => 'Press me I am a button :D',
            ),
        ));
```

The annotation equivalent would be:

```
* @Annotation\Attributes({"data-toggle":"tooltip", "data-placement":"left", "title":"Press me I am a button :D"})
```

Comment: BTW: how big of a performance hit are we talking about when using annotations?

Comment: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/annotations.md

Since annotations come with doctrine there is a whole lot of mapping and parsing involved and it produces a overhead. While the zf form does that 2 in some way I believe I read that it does that in a more performant way. I also believe I have read it was by a big margin.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to initialize

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```